Query Events at meetup via GraphQL
Trying to query meetups API for parts of an event as shown here:
https://www.meetup.com/api/schema/#Event
Especially checking "rsvpSearch" it states it needs:
rsvpSearch(
input:ConnectionInput
filter:RsvpSearchFilter REQUIRED
):(RsvpSearchConnection) REQUIRED

But I can't find what values are exactly required for "RsvpSearchFilter" and how to add them.
Does anyone have an idea how or where to find them?
https://www.meetup.com/api/schema/#RsvpSearchFilter just states
query:(String) REQUIRED

but not what the string has to be. HOW has it to look?
